# Doubts about publishing priority

Tags: journals, books, philosophy

My doubt is this: if I first publish with a serious academic publisher a small book which gives an overall view of my philosophy of science proposal, could I legitimately try to publish afterwards some journal articles detailing the main specific theoretical questions touched upon in the book, or would it be a no-no and considered by the potential journals a form of double submission or attemp to publish non original content?

More specifically, I could distinguish two cases:

a) I try to submit the material to be published as a book, but I am still waiting for a response from the publisher. At the same time, I try to submit to various different journals (by the same publisher or not) some papers which describe in more detail some of the fundamental questions which are touched upon in a more coarse manner in the book.

b) The book has been already published and only aftwerwards I try to submit the detailed papers.

Would the above be legitimate practices? Or should I try only publish articles detailing questions and proposals not already touched in another publication of mine? Consider that the articles would surely add detail to the questions touched upon in the book, but that the basic lines of the arguments would be more or less the same.

I recently achieved a PhD in Philosophy of Science, and I am still not very expert in the topic of academic publications, so this is probably a naive doubt. I tried to ask my PhD supervisor but I'm not quite convinced by his answers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps this is not the case in philosophy, but I would think the "fleshing out ideas" part would be done in journal articles and then later the "tying everything together in a cohesive manner" part would be done in a book.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro my understanding (as someone in an early career stage in philosophy) agrees with you. Publish journal articles first, then book is the normal pattern.

Comment: Small /question: by "doubt", do you mean what I would usually call "enquiry" or "question"?

Comment: @Yemon@Choi of course if you want you could translate "doubt" with "question" or "enquiry", but I honestly do not understand the spirit of your comment. Maybe with that title I have broken some etiquette in Stackexchange? Would you please cclarify your comment?

Comment: @CesarMoncalvo I take it that Yemon is confused because "My doubt is this" is a weird way to start a question and to refer to a normal question at least as used in my dialect of English (American English).

Comment: @virmaior, you're certainly right... English is not my mother tongue. I'm sorry to have engendered perplexity, I just wanted to convey the fact that the question reflects a doubt of mine about how to proceed with my publications